# Config Kivy > Invert input for y axis

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3, kivy-language

I am trying to setup a "off-brand" touchscreen on a Raspberry Pi3 and I am having some trouble when I run my python/kivy program, visually everything is fine, but whenever I need to move a slider, push a button or whatever. the input y-axis is inverted, note that it works fine when i run this on my windows machine
 [As you can see the input for the buttons are inverted on the y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psjr6.jpg)

I do know this exists and I have tried it, but it did nothing to solve the problem (In my case).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344458/7522859

And I have tried to fix it in the config file under (in my case) (.kivy/config.ini), and as you can see it reads the invert_y option but does nothing with both 1 and 0 as its values.

```
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/64D933A55CDD560F/PrinterSoftware# python MC.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-02-06_10.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2.dev0, git-57d41c9, 20170206
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event2
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event2>
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Set custom invert_y to 0
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

So the question is how do I invert the Y-axis for the input in the kivy config file. I have also taken a look at [this](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.providers.hidinput.html) and I didn't really understand it that well, maybe I am just stupid.

Sorry if this post is bad. Its my first post and English is not my native language.

Comment: `invert_x : 1` in the config file

Comment: It did nothing or I just didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work, finally.

I changed the line 417 in the `hidinput.py` under:

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/hidinput.py`

Credit: [How do if invert touch input in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447656/how-do-if-invert-touch-input-in-kivy/34344458#34344458)

and set the config:

```
~/.kivy/config.ini
```

under [input]

```
ADS7846 = hidinput,/dev/input/event2,invert_y=0
```